# Can I change what happens to Astrid in the Dark Brotherhood quest line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to

> save Astrid during the Dark Brotherhood questline?

It makes me really sad to see this happen.

Comment: You could always let Cicero live? Then you'd have a whole 3 assassins.

Comment: Can I just say that the recent edit to this question is awful and probably works against prople finding this question on a search?

Comment: I agree, I think the edit sacrifices too much of the question on the alter of "no spoilers." I've tried to put some useful searchable terms back into the title while still preserving the gory details behind the spoiler tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note, the following are spoilers for TES: V, regarding Astrid:

> No. You can't save her; no matter what you do, Astrid dies during the [Death Incarnate](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Death_Incarnate) quest.
> If you really wanted, and you're playing on the PC, you may be able to use console commands to place her (`RefID 0001BDE8`) somewhere via `moveto` or `placeatme`. She will presumably operate based on her generic AI package or at the very least just stand there (as `0001BDE8` is the "regular" Astrid and the one you see in the above quest is a different technical entity, `0004D6D1`).

Answer (score 2):

I am very late, and am probably necro'ing this post. But there is a mod on the Nexus that allows you to bring her back and have her as a follower, voice of Cindy Robinson and all.

It is called [Astrid Reborn.](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/54009)